# Can I run electrical cable in old unused heating ducts?

Tags: electrical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the NEC allow electrical wiring to run next to a ventilation duct?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/does-the-nec-allow-electrical-wiring-to-run-next-to-a-ventilation-duct)

My house has recently been converted to 200-amp electrical service, and I would love to run some new wire to take advantage of that fact.  My house was converted from forced air to hot-water baseboard heating.  My question is:  can I run electrical wire through the old heating ducts to save myself quite a bit of hassle?  What if there are hot water pipes in them?  Is it advisable to/must I use conduit, or would Romex suffice?

Comment: ^ while the question is not the same, KeithS provides the answer to your question (short answer: no)

Answer (score 1):

I will let someone else weigh in on the NEC compliance, but likely it is allowed (I am guessing it is the same as retrofitting and fishing a wire through an empty wall cavity).

However, I would definitely not do this with NM wire, since there's a high chance there are sharp metal edges and other protrusions that can damage the wire creating a safety and fire hazard. BX (armoured) would be more appropriate, and easier than trying to get NM through conduit and into the vents.

Comment: You don't see a problem with either the completely empty ducts, or the ones with the hot water pipes?